# how to run Json server along with ReactJS on same port

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, json-server

I am trying to run React application using JSON server- as my backend API.
But getting CORS error while running on different port

I need some solution so that i can run on same port
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: I am also facing same problem

Comment: Set up a dev proxy? It's built into Create React App via Webpack dev server. Or actually set the right headers on the API? It depends what your actual production deployment is going to look like.

Answer (score 0):

You can't open the same port twice.

You have basically two options

1. Setup a proxy
2. Implement CORS headers

### Proxy

You can integrate proxy directly using nodejs - CRA supports this option: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/

```
Conveniently, this avoids CORS issues and error messages like this in development:

Fetch API cannot load http://localhost:4000/api/todos. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

### Implement CORS

Implement CORS headers is not as hard as it might look like.

Please see the documentation of the json server: https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-server

```
const jsonServer = require('json-server')
const server = jsonServer.create()
const middlewares = jsonServer.defaults()

// Set default middlewares (logger, static, cors and no-cache)
server.use(middlewares)
```

There is also a CLI option if you use json-server directly via command line. By default, CORS are enabled. Therefore it seems that you need the `jsonServer.defaults()` to create your middlewares.